# Magento 2 How can I show custom options on product list page

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I am trying to display custom options in product list page. Can any one give me idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Custom option means new attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Override file in ur theme

**magento\app\design\frontend\Vendor\YourThemeName\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml**

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
 echo $attrName = $_product->getAttributeText('your_attribute_name');
endforeach;
```

Go to Admin & Your Custom Attribute, Edit it. In `Storefront Properties` -> `Used in Product Listing` set to **Yes**